# new Font Family in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, font-family

## what is the difference between "Create downloadable font" and "Add font to project"?

[image]

## what is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Create downloadable font**" refers to creating a font that can be downloaded and installed on the device at runtime. This allows the font to be dynamically loaded by the application and provides a flexible way to change the font without requiring an update to the app.

"**Add font to project**" refers to adding the font directly to the project resources, which will be packaged with the app when it is built. This makes the font available to the application at all times and is a simpler solution for small projects or for cases where the font will not change.

The choice between the two methods depends on the requirements of the project, including the size of the font file, the need for dynamic updates, and the requirement to install the font on the device.

Comment: Welcome if it helps you then please mark it as verify answer and upvote. for helping others.

Comment: It was completed